# How to get URL string in ZF2 controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want URL in controller method from the route.

```
$route = $this->url('my/route', array('id' => $myID), array(
                'force_canonical' => true,
                    ));
```

This will give me the route object but what I want is URL like

```
$link = "http://example.com/my/route/23"
```

in a variable as I have to send it to other action for display as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can generate URL from route this way :

```
$params = array('id' => $myID);
$url = $this->url()->fromRoute('my/route', $params);
```

Doc: (http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html)